# PHP: How to explode string

Tags: php, file, explode

I have a variable that stores the location of a temp file:

```
$file = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\filename.tmp';
```

How can I explode all this to get `filename` (without the path and extension)?
Thanks.

Comment: Well you use the word you are looking for in the question as a start. Did you try to use that word/function? (Explode)

Comment: Will it be dynamic in nature? Meaning you don't know the name of or type of file ext. Have you researched explode method in PHP manual? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

Is not the best code but if you confident that this path will be similar and just file name will be different you can use this code:

```
$str = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\filename.tmp';

$arrayExplode = explode("\\", $str);
$file = $arrayExplode[count($arrayExplode)-1];

$filename = explode('.', $file);
$filename = $filename[0];

echo  $filename;
```

Advice: Watch out on the path contain "n" like the first letter after the backslash. It could destroy your array.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the [basename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function, it's meant specifically for that.